# Surveys in Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, survey

I have created a simple Survey in classic content. I was wondering what the equivalent option is in content builder. Does anyone have any feedback on what they have used/set up surveys. I have used Clicktools and Survey Monkey before but wanted to explore the possibility of exploiting the features of the Marketing cloud.

Comment: Are you trying to collect information as a form fill-out?  Check out Web Collect.  It's hosted in the Cloud Pages.  http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/

Comment: The information would be about the experience that the customer has had recently (eg Service Case) Ideally this information would need to filter back into our connected Salesforce environment. I have been told that this is initially going to contain just a few questions with a Radio Group and Free Text question options.